# nivoSlider undefined resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, nivo-slider

I am trying to get nivoSlider to work on this site http://fritech.co.uk/ where it has three images

```
<div id="slideshow" class="section theme-nivo">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="static/img/logos.png" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
        <img src="static/img/atlanta.png" alt="Modern technologies" />
        <img src="static/img/boston.png" alt="Ruggedly tested software" />
    </div>
</div>
```

However nivoSlider is only showing one of them, always the top one. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you change static/js/libs/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js with the development version ? That will make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: @helmus that's done now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding the `#slideshow` id to the wrong container in your html:

```
<div id="top" class="bordered-section">
    <div id="slideshow" class="section theme-nivo">
        <div class="ribbon"></div>
        <div class="nivoSlider">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Modern technologies" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Ruggedly tested software" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ID should be placed on the container of your images which are being used as background images.

Fixed.

```
<div id="top" class="bordered-section">
    <div class="section theme-nivo">
        <div class="ribbon"></div>
        <div id="slideshow" class="nivoSlider">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Modern technologies" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Ruggedly tested software" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find the proper usage under the plugins [Documentation](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/).

Comment: @Meitham, i answered first, i gave the exact reason what went wrong ( as you requested ) , and i was already looking at this yesterday, why do i not get the bounty ?

Comment: @helmus Thank you for your efforts in answering this. Your answers are equally greats however I have found the reference to the documentation andres-ilich put is an extra bonus. If there was a way to divide the bounty over the two of you I would have done so. I have also voted your question up to give extra points.

Answer (score 3):

Found it !

please change this

```
<div id="slideshow" class="section theme-nivo">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="static/img/logos.png" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
        <img src="static/img/atlanta.png" alt="Modern technologies" />
        <img src="static/img/boston.png" alt="Ruggedly tested software" />
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="section theme-nivo">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slideshow" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="static/img/logos.png" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
        <img src="static/img/atlanta.png" alt="Modern technologies" />
        <img src="static/img/boston.png" alt="Ruggedly tested software" />
    </div>
</div>
```

NivoSlider expects all children from the top element to be images, if the element is not an image it will look for the first image it can find in that element.
( see here )

- https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js#L44

That is why you are getting a loop of an undefined image and the logo image.
Because the ribbon element does not contain any images, and the first image from the nivoSlider element is the logo.

Answer (score 0):

There is some thing wrong, maybe you are requesting for an image which do not exist on server or in that folder. Because in firefox console (**FireBug**) it is throwing this **error**

**undefined
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://fritech.co.uk/undefined"**

else everything looks fine. Please double check the images you are trying to load in slider.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The images are all there. If you do view source and click on the links they will open up. However, it is nivoSlider that is returning the image path as undefined which is resulting with a 404.

Comment: can you please set controlNavThumbsFromRel to 'false' in your settings and then give it a try.

Comment: that didn't work. I have also set the image paths to absolute and still failing.

Answer (score 0):

For documentation about your situation,

i just encountered something similar, "**k is not defined**" ..

it happened to be a missing `title` attribute in the `img` tag

```
<img title="" src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Our inhouse skills" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem try change your js to this
http://pastebin.com/7QPV2rgr

Comment: I'm using jQuery Nivo Slider v2.7.1 are you suggesting to use v1.9 ? That is not compatible with my current jQuery which 1.7.1

Comment: I'm running this one https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js